# What is the technical name for numeric properties that represent a positive or negative range?

Tags: math, numbers, computer-science, terminology

What is the technical term to describe a numeric property that is a range from `—n` to `n`. For example: `—1.0` to `1.0` or `—300` to `300`. In this situation, `0` is usually the default or middle.

Contrast this with a numeric property representing natural numbers. Ex: `0-400` or `0-∞`. In these examples, `0` is the lowest value, not the middle.

Comment: An interval that is symmetrical with respect to zero?

Answer (score 1):

That's an [interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)).

If it includes the endpoints, it's called a *closed interval*.
If the endpoints are excluded, it's called an *open interval*.

Comment: Yes, but is there a special name for an interval that is symmetrical with respect to zero? I don't think so.

Comment: I guess you could call it a point in the [0-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) but that's getting a bit abstract... :)

Comment: Thanks! Is there an analogous term for the `0+` ranges? Like if I want to say: "It's not a ___. It's an interval."

Comment: And actually now that I think about it. I think I'm looking for a slightly more specific term to describe an interval that is symmetrical w.r.t. zero. Because `23` to `441` is also an interval right?

Comment: On some level, I think I'm hoping for a term that helps communicate the intent. For example, a database field that can be -10 to 10 is generally a more intuitive way to "weight" something... even though the same calculations *could* technically be done with an interval from 20 to 40. The latter is just arbitrary and weird.

Comment: So maybe what I'm pinpointing is that I'm trying to describe the _property_ as much as the numbers themselves. Does that make sense?

Comment: You asked for a "numeric property that **is a** range" .. do you actually want an adjective that's describing a number contained in the range, i.e. an element of the interval?

Comment: How about "a segment on the real number line with midpoint at 0" [or "at the origin" if you want to be fancy].

Comment: Also, if it includes one endpoint you have to decide if you are an optimist or pessimist. It is half-open or half-closed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Wikipedia article on [intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)), a symmetrical interval about zero has been referred to as a "balanced interval":

> Every interval can be considered a symmetric interval around its midpoint. In a reconfiguration published in 1956 by M Warmus, the axis of **"balanced intervals" [x, −x]** is used along with the axis of intervals [x,x] that reduce to a point.